# Google Chrome background-size:cover;

Tags: google-chrome, css

i dont know why, but if i use this property i get lagged between transitions. It just happen under chrome 15, i tried IE, FF and Safari and the transition between pages are not lagged like Chroome. Any ideas to solve this issue? 
You can test it here: http://jaimeanglada.es/
Try to click in the main menu to see that in chrome its not smooth like others webbrowsers.

On style.css:

```
.pages > div {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If i remove this the transition between pages on Chrome is good.

Comment: Is this question still valid?

Comment: i dont think so, can i erase it?

Comment: You can *flag* it as question to be closed.